# How to display the Hyperlink vertically in SharePoint 2010 server?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, out-of-the-box

I have a SharePoint list(Test) with hyperlink field.I want to use Out of the Box Features in SharePoint 2010.In home page i want to add one webpart it will get the links form Test list and it should display this hyperlink vertically.

When we are clicking the hyperlink it should open in another window.

please refer the image below.

[image]
can you please some one help me on this how i can achieve this using SharePoint out of the box feature.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list already has a column whose type is hyperlink, create a View in your list (you could refer to [this](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-modify-or-delete-a-view-10c68afb-d901-4b15-848b-82d399eba089#__toc237324407) step if needed), which only displays that hyperlink field.

Then you could just add a web part on your home page, like you usually do (you could refer to [this](http://www.isacantx.org/SharePointTraining/TrainingPages/ListView.html) step if needed).

On the **Selected View** dropdownlist (step 9 from the link before), select the view you've created. Click OK to apply it, and your web part will displays only the hyperlink field.

Comment: hi this is i already tried  But the item count is increased pagination will come in listview. but it should be scrolling down vertically within the webpart.Before that hyperlink  i want to add Images.

Comment: If you need the list to have 'infinite vertical scroll', then you need to implement custom code / script. I've never heard OOTB solutions for that before.. but maybe there is some scripts you could try (with a little modification) like: https://gist.github.com/marineko/7a1061a633f5e21560ee